# Changing ec2 instance type from m4.4xlarge to m5a.4xlarge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've an m4.4xlarge instance running Percona MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I plan to change the instance family to m5a.4xlarge. Are there any unforeseen problems that I might run into when doing this or is it just a matter of shutting down the instance, changing the instance type and restarting it again? Are there any linux kernel level compatibility issues that I need to look into?

Comment: Make an AMI of the m4 instance, fire up an m5 instance with that AMI, and run your tests.

Comment: Should work fine as per answer below. Note that the device names can change, and you might need to install a driver - can't remember what it was but it's related to Nitro. Suggest you take a snapshot, create an AMI, and test it with the new instance type before you change the production instance type.

Answer (score 2):

The only potential data issue would be if you used instance store (as opposed to Elastic Block Storage) for the disk, but that's unlikely. Also, the IP address of the instance will change, so any applications that depend on that IP will need to be configured with the new IP. And as @ceejayoz pointed out, it's easy enough to test!

Comment: Will the private IP change as well? For public IP, we have associated an elastic IP to this instance.

Comment: @Deb Yes, the private IP will be different. You can reassign the Elastic IP to the new instance.

Comment: Whenever I've rebooted the instance or upgraded the instance within the same instance family, I've not seen the private IP changing. Are you saying that this does change when we change from instance family to the other?

Comment: Yes the private IP will change - the instance will need to stop & start, which causes this. Rebooting is different and doesn't cause an IP to change.

Comment: In the same instance family, I've actually upgraded by stopping the instance, changing the instance type and starting the instance a good number of times in the past. But I've not seen the private IP change.

Quoting from the aws docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html

"A private IPv4 address remains associated with the network interface when the instance is stopped and restarted, and is released when the instance is terminated."

Comment: Thanks for correcting that